# How to Design/Figure out the Required Path in Ruby Programming?

Tags: ruby, path

Is there a well-designed method that can run my ruby program from anywhere? I already searched a couple of ways to import my ruby program from the different directories by using the relative path.

i.e.

> File.expand_path(“my_path”)

It worked and let me run it anywhere, but somehow, it is a little unreadable and I think it is pretty messy.  So I think there may be a solution or convention to deal with this kind of problem when there are many file paths that have to be imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have a look [how to package a gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/) and build your own and install it. Or you could place your binary in `$PATH`, but that's a bit more messy.